# code passes example but doesn't give correct output(project euler number 22)

Tags: python-3.x

My code for Project euler number 22 returns the correct awnser for the example but for the main question it returns 871323337 which is wrong.

**Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score.
For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.
What is the total of all the name scores in the file?**

```
y=[]
for a in range(1,len(x)+1):
    s="zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
    for b in x:
        if b<s:
            s=b
    y.append(s)
    x.remove(s)
def letter_to_int(letter):
    return int(ord(letter)-64)
def sum_in_string(s):
    t=0
    for i in s:
        if i=='!':
            break
        t=t+letter_to_int(i)
    return t+60
t=0
for i in range(0,len(y)):
    t=t+sum_in_string(y[i])*(i+1)
print(t)
```

Comment: What do you want us to tell you?

Comment: @BillBell Could you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I would agree with what Nate said in the comment to his answer. That's good advice in general if you want others to read your code.

Comment: @BillBell I edited my code so I hope it's more readable.could you tell me what my problems are?

Comment: I'm not going to attempt to understand your entire script: too much work. It might help if you chose names that indicate what the variables represent. For instance, what is `a`, what is `x`, what is `y`? And so on, Beyond that, there is the structure of your code. I cannot see how it reflects the structure of the problem at hand. You don't read the file, for instance. You don't sort it. You don't read it line by line. These are characteristics that most of us would look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will work:

```
names = ["MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH" . . . .]

alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", 
            "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

names = sorted(names)
total_score = 0
for i in range(0, len(names)):
    name = names[i]

    letter_score = 0
    for letter in name:
        letter_score += alphabet.index(letter) + 1

    total_score += (i+1) * letter_score


print(total_score)
```

The result is 871198282
Make sure to vote this answer as correct if it works!

Comment: Could you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I cant really tell what your code is doing. It would help a lot if you made it clear what your variables and external functions are. Also, its a good idea to use multi-worded function names more than 3 characters long. Without any understanding at all of you code, all that I can advise is that you clean it and make sure that you correctly imported the file, numbered the letters, and numbered the names. Try restarting - its often a lot easier than fixing what is already broken.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!